# Quadratic transform of the uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, transformation

Consider $X$ as a uniform distribution over $[-1, 3]$. Let $Y = X^2 + 4X$
(a)  Find $f_Y(y)$.
(b) Verify that $f_Y(y)$ is a PDF.

Comment: Have solved similar problems with just X^2 but I don't know how to deal with the addition of 4X

Comment: We get lucky, $x^2+4x$ is increasing in our interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$
\begin{split}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] \\
       &= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}\left[X^2 + 4X \le y\right] \\
       &= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}\left[X^2 + 4X + 4\le y + 4\right] \\
       &= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}\left[(X+2)^2 \le y + 4\right]
\end{split}
$$
Now you convert this to an expression of the $F_X(y)$ and when you differentiate you get an expression in $f_X(y)$, both of which are known.